# problem with jquery tablesorter with dynamic added rows

Tags: jquery, javascript

hello i am having a problem with dynamically added rows to jquery tablesorter,

i have to add a row in the beginning of the table, by default the tablesorter works fine but after the row is added, the table sorted only sorts using the previous rows i mean that the new row is not included in the sorting process, the new row has some but not all fields blank any solution?

Answer (score 22, accepted):

The tablesorter website offers details of how to do this, at: [Appending table data with Ajax](http://tablesorter.com/docs/example-ajax.html). The code is reproduced below:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("table").tablesorter();
    $("#ajax-append").click(function() {
        $.get("assets/ajax-content.html", function(html) {
            // append the "ajax'd" data to the table body 
            $("table tbody").append(html);
            // let the plugin know that we made a update 
            // updateAll ensures sorting is updated as well
            $("table").trigger("updateAll");
            // set sorting column and direction, this will sort on the first and third column 
            var sorting = [[2, 1], [0, 0]];
            // sort on the first column 
            $("table").trigger("sorton", [sorting]);
        });
        return false;
    });
});
```

Comment: i have tried it and it didn't work, and i am not using any ajax call, i am making the row by cloning an existing row in the table might this cause a problem?

Comment: fixed!, just needed to add, $('your table').trigger("appendCache");

Comment: @Shaheer: which line in above script should I add $('your table').trigger("appendCache") to make it work

Comment: @learnJQueryUI just adding `$("table").trigger("update");` after adding content via ajax worked for me

Comment: $("table").trigger("update"); this one worked . A ton of thanks

Answer (score 1):

You tried to unset the tablesorter and initialize a new tablesorter session?

Because the tablesorter dont know you added the new rows, so why not set a new tablesorter on the table.

Answer (score -1):

The only way I could make it working was to regenerate whole table (remove it and then create again).

```
$(".resultTablePlaceholder").html('').html('<table id="resultTable">...</table>');
$("#resultTable").tablesorter();
```

Answer (score -1):

These lines worked perfectly for me. After assigning HTML just trigger the update function of table.

```
$('#tblID').html(str);
$("#tblID").trigger("update");
```

where `#tblID` is the table ID and `str` is the html of table rows assigned to table.