# AJAX appended collapsible rows to a jQuery/javascript Tablesorter table lack needed attributes

Tags: jquery, ajax, html-table, toggle, tablesorter

I'm trying to append rows upon scrolling of a table using a modified version of Tablesorter.js: http://www.pengoworks.com/workshop/jquery/tablesorter/tablesorter.htm. It is modified in the sense that it allows for collapsible rows.

The problem I'm having is that upon scrolling and an AJAX call to load new rows, these new rows are lacking the attributes of the other rows that allow them to be toggleably collapsed/expanded.

Here's some issues with the HTML for these appended rows:

1. the clickable `<a>` tag class name isn't being toggled from "expanded" to "collapsible"
2. the toggled `<td>` columns style attributes aren't  defaulting to `"display:none"` and don't toggle to `"display: table-cell"`.

Here's the JS to trigger AJAX request upon scrolling and for Tablesorter. I've kept the HTML exactly as in the demo in the pengoworks.com link i mentioned above.

```
    $(function(){   
        $(document).endlessScroll({ 
            callback: function(i) { 
            loaded += 10;
                $.post("/more/" + loaded, function(data){
                    $("#table"+ " tbody").append(data);
                    $("#table").trigger("update");
                }); 
            } 
        }); 

        $("#table").collapsible("td.collapsible", {
                collapse: true
            }).tablesorter({
            sortList: [[1,0]],      
            headers: {0: {sorter: false}}
            , widgets: ['zebra']
                , onRenderHeader: function (){
                    this.wrapInner("<span></span>");
                }
            });
  });
```

**UPDATE** Please see the following jsfiddle which aims to get at AJAXifying the collapsible tablesorter table: 
http://jsfiddle.net/Lcztc/8. 
It's not true AJAX but you get the idea. Also, here's a link to the collapsible.js code: http://www.pengoworks.com/workshop/jquery/tablesorter/jquery.tablesorter.collapsible.js. According to Amar (see below), It is pretty clear I need to fix the parts of that plugin that relate to table element bindings such that they recognize appended elements.

Unfortunately, the above jsfiddle still has 2 major issue with it: 1) the collapsibility of the original rows is lost every other time you click the "clickAJAX" button; 2) appended rows are never collapsible or expandable. Still some progress...

Comment: thanks Richard, i just updated my question, see above...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can check this, not sure but this may be the probable cause.

When you retrieve the data and append it to the table, the binding of the `a` tags in the new html is not happening. In other words, if you have 10 anchor tags in beginning(which are toggelable), after scrolling, you get new 5 tags, these tags are not binded to the handler, and because of this they are not getting toggled. This might be the issue with `td`.

You can explore `.on()` jQuery function.

In OP's case, he is using older version of jQuery(1.6.4), so he will need to use `.live()`

I hope this info helps you. If you could have provided more info, I could have helped more accurate answer.

Comment: It looks like similar issue, what I was trying to explain. You will need to bind both `collapsible` and `tablesorter`.

Comment: You can try richard's solution. It might solve your issue. The answer I have given is the main problem, binding of event handler to the new items is not happening.

Comment: hi Amar, i'm just confused because some of the binding but not all of it is happening. To address Richard's solution, I did use "$("table").trigger("update");" in my code. The rows and HTML elements are being appended it's just that their attributes, namely the <a> class="expanded/collapsed" and <td> style="display:none" aren't being set.

Comment: How are they applied in the first time? I don't know about your table plugin. Is there any custom code or plugin does it for you. If plugin is doing, then use same code to rebind the whole table.

Comment: hi Amar, can you offer some advice on how to alter the binding of the collapsible() function? I've added a jsfiddle to my question to get us started. I've also attached a link to the collapsible.js file. I'm not familiar with jQuery/javascript so I don't really know where to start to modify that file to suit my needs. thanks, -tim

Comment: I have updated the jsFiddle. Try this one http://jsfiddle.net/Lcztc/1/. There is comment //Main Code. The code below this is adding the classes as you requested. If you click the button, you will see it. This much I can help you in your issue. The grid is sorting also. Hope this helps you.

Comment: thanks Amar, i've updated your code to fix the collapsiblity of table rows: http://jsfiddle.net/trpeters1/Lcztc/6/ . Unfortunately, when you do the append(), you can't do the collapse on the rows anymore. Doesn't it seem that the function "assignCollapsible() isn't actually assigned to act on the table? thanks, -tim

Comment: Your markup is not correct in the given jsFiddle. Check this one http://jsfiddle.net/Lcztc/8/. There are odd and even rows, and every row has extra row as `<tr class='expand-child'>`. So its like Odd TR => expand-child TR => Even TR => expand-child TR => Odd TR => expand-child. Check the markup.

Comment: thanks Amar, the javascript in your jsfiddle isn't quite correct, it only allows collapsing/expanding of rows on every OTHER clickAJAX. Would you mind fixing the javascript so that like the original rows, each appended row can be collapsed or expanded? thanks, tim

Comment: In your original example also they are not collapsing or expanding. http://jsfiddle.net/trpeters1/pXdB3/17/

Comment: sorry about that, i was having a hard enough time getting others parts of the code to work, it was the first time i made a jsfiddle

Answer (score 0):

You can't just add HTML to Tablesorter after it has been initialized. It won't 'understand' it.

Have a look at this post: [problem with jquery tablesorter with dynamic added rows](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4574057/problem-with-jquery-tablesorter-with-dynamic-added-rows)

After you have added the HTML, you must update the tablesorter; `$("table").trigger("update");`

See also: http://tablesorter.com/docs/example-ajax.html

Comment: hi Richard, I did use "$("table").trigger("update");" in my code. The rows and HTML elements are being appended it's just that their attributes, namely the <a> class="expanded/collapsed" and <td> style="display:none" aren't being set.

Comment: Can you please post the initial HTML that is loaded for the table in your initial question? Or preferably set-up an example on jsfiddle.net? That'll help analyzing.

Comment: hi Richard, ok here it is, the AJAX part doesn't work yet on this fiddle but you get the idea: http://jsfiddle.net/trpeters1/pXdB3/16/. Here's the base example without attempting to incorporate endless scrolling http://jsfiddle.net/pXdB3/